# Assigning random points within polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, random

I have a vector layer with multiple polygons. I converted the layer to a raster layer in order to convert the raster cells to points (I needed my points to be in rows). Is there a way to combine the points and polygons, in a way that I could assign all points within the same polygon one value and other points within a different polygon different values for the points. I would like the points within the polygon to have the same values, but different polygons will have different point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that depending on what value you want to be assigned to your points.

**Route 1 - if you used a unique value to create your polygons**

If you used a unique value within the attributes of your polygon layer to create your raster, so that the raster cells corresponding to each polygon have a different value, then you can run a tool such as [Extract Raster Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) - this will transfer your raster values to the points. This does require a Spatial Analyst license.

**Route 2 - if you didn't use a unique value to create your polygons**

If all your raster cells have the same value then you will need to go back to your original polygon shapefile. Open the attribute table for your polygon layer and create a new field. Populate this with the values that you want to assign to the points - or obviously use an existing field if you have it already.
You can then run a [spatial join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) . This will add the attributes of the polygons to the points depending on their spatial location.